# Почему потомок не может увидеть свойство родителя?

Tags: python

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 10

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


obj_C = C(55)
print(obj_C.val)
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'val'

Неужели единственный способ - это явно указать наследование:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        A.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        B.__init__(self)
```